# Flutter - http post request parameter is not taken

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, request

I want to get a list of animes from server by POST request (this is a search, so I make a POST request, with a string parameter). I have got a code from site, which works and returns two-three animes - this is correct response, and my app return a bit list of animes. Why does it happens? I give the same parameter 'hello'.

Here is a Javascript code, it works:

```
    let body = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(getParameterByName('search'));
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.open("POST", "https://api.animevost.org/v1/search", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    req.onload = function () {
        unpackLastTitles(req.response);
    };

    req.onerror = function () {
        alert("Загрузка не удалась");
    };
    console.log(9898, body, req);

    req.send(body);
```

And here is my Flutter code, it return the big list of anime (instead of searched ones) regardless of what you search:

```
final response = await http.post(
          Uri.https('api.animevost.org', '/v1/search', {'name': tC.text}),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
                "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send that as a body parameter.

```dart
final response = await http.post(
   Uri.https('api.animevost.org', '/v1/search'),
   body: {'name': tC.text}, // Setting as body parameter
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
         "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
});
```